# Calculate SUM of column based on another column SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am working on creating a SSRS report that requires me to "have a column that gives me the number for the offer and out of that number how many enrolled."  I have attached a screenshot of what I have done so far.  I need to figure out how to create an expression (if there is a better way to go about this) that would use following logic:  Get SUM of Count column where Enrolled = 'Yes'.  Is this possible in SSRS?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now your summary expression probably looks something like this

```
= Sum(Fields!Count.Value)
```

If so - all you need to do is add a condition include only records with Enrolled = "Yes"

```
= Sum(IIF(Fields!Enrolled.Value = "Yes", Fields!Count.Value, 0))
```